# Rigorously show that $x\mapsto x^{\alpha}$ is monotonically increasing for all $\alpha>0$.

Tags: real-analysis

How would one rigorously prove that $x^\alpha$ is monotonically increasing for all $\alpha>0$? I know it should be simple but I'm finding it surprisingly difficult. I tried to argue that $x^\alpha=e^{\alpha \ln(x)}$ and since
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{\alpha \ln(x)}=\frac{\alpha e^{\alpha \ln (x)}}{x}
$$
and the RHS is positive for all $x > 0$, we have that $x^\alpha$ is monotonically increasing. My two questions are: (1) is this argument correct, and (2) is there a more direct proof that does not require rewriting $x^\alpha$ using $e$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x>0$ we have by definition for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$ x^{\alpha} = \mathrm{e}^{\ln(x)\alpha}$$

Firstly for all $\alpha>0$,

$$x \in \mathbb{R}_+^*\mapsto \alpha\ln(x) $$ is monotonically increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ because $\ln$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$.

Furthermore, $\exp$ is monotonically increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ therefore by composition, we have

$$x \in \mathbb{R}_+^* \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\ln(x)\alpha}= x^{\alpha} $$

monotonically increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. Note that $x^{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha$ real number is actually defined in this way, so if you start with this definition this is one of the easiest and most direct way to prove it.

Comment: Note there are problems when $x < 0$ with that definition. But it seems from OP question he's restricting to $x \ge 0$ anyway.

Comment: Yes indeed, I gave for granted the domain given by the log function

Answer (score 0):

You are using the geometric meaning of the derivative and it is correct. Another way of solving it is... see what happen(COMPARE) to the image of $x$ and $y$ through $f(z)=z^{\alpha}$ when $0<x<y$. We wished that $x^{\alpha}<y^{\alpha} \iff (\frac{x}{y})^{\alpha}<1$ and this is true once $x<y\iff \frac{x}{y}<1$.